# Visual Studio Compiler warning C4250 ('class1' : inherits 'class2::member' via dominance)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, warnings, multiple-inheritance

The following code generates warning C4250. My question is, what's the best solution to it?

```
class A
{
  virtual void func1();
}

class B : public A
{
}

class C : public A
{
  virtual void func1();
}

class D : public B, public C
{
}

int main()
{
  D d;
  d.func1(); // Causes warning
}
```

According to what I've read it should be possible to do this:

```
class D : public B, public C
{
  using B::func1();
}
```

But, this doesn't actually do anything. The way I've currently solved it is:

```
class D : public B, public C
{
  virtual void func1() { B::func1(); }
}
```

What's everyone's view on this?

Comment: The code in the first block doesn't compile and after changing it to compile it doesn't generate C4250.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same warning for the following code:

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void A() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public virtual Interface
{
public:
    virtual void A() {};
};

class ExtendedInterface : public virtual Interface
{
    virtual void B() = 0;
};

class ExtendedImplementation : public ExtendedInterface , public Implementation
{
public:
    virtual void B() {};
};
```

This [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=101259) for Visual C++ 2005 in msdn suggests that this is a known bug that was considered not important enough to fix... They suggest to disable the warning in this case by using a pragma. I think it is safe also in your case, but you should use virtual inheritance as shown in the answer by Gal Goldman.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try to inherit public virtual from class A? I think it should solve it.

```
    class B :public virtual A;
    class C :public virtual A;
    class D : public virtual B, public virtual C;
```

The virtual inheritance suppose to solve the ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, even with virtual inheritance it still has the same problem (there are two suitable functions to call, the compiler just chooses the most "overridden" one)

Comment: Then I guess there's no escape from your suggested solution.

Comment: I compiled your code now in VS2005 and without the virtual it's actually an error, not a warning. With the virtual it's a warning.

Answer (score 1):

[A comment really, but I don't have enough rep...]

David Segonds identified this as a known bug in VS 2005, just tried his example code in VS 2008 and it exhibits the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you're using may be the way to go, sorry to say. The only thing I can think of that might help is if you're able to make A's func1 pure virtual. That might not be feasible in your real program, though.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug in visual studio which means that warning will still appear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easy solve

```
class A
{
  virtual void func1();
}

class B : public A
{
}

class C : public A
{
  virtual void func1();
}

class D : public B, public C
{
  virtual void func1()
  {
    C::func1(); 
  }
}

int main()
{
  D d;
  d.func1(); // Causes warning
}
```