# Inheritance with interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the basics of C++ inheritance. Consider the following piece of code:

```
// Interfaces

class InterfaceBase
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

class InterfaceInherited : public InterfaceBase
{
};

// Classes

class ClassBase : public InterfaceBase
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
};

class ClassInherited : public ClassBase, public InterfaceInherited
{
};

int main()
{
    ClassBase myBase; // OK
    ClassInherited myInherited; // Error on this line

  return 0;
}
```

Here I have two interfaces with an inheritance relationship. The same goes for the two classes which implement the interfaces.

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
C2259 'ClassInherited': cannot instantiate abstract class
```

It seems that the class **ClassInherited** does not inherit the implementation of **SomeMethod** from **ClassBase**. Thus it is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

How would I need to modify this simple example in order to let **ClassInherited** inherit all the implemented methods from **ClassBase**?

Comment: In this case there's no need to inherit `ClassInherit` from `InterfaceInherited` _again_. It already inherits that interface from `ClassBase`.

Comment: The fact is that it is inheriting from both `ClassBase` and from `InterfaceInherited`, but the last one has not defined the `SomeMethod` implementation, so that one is still pending in `ClassInherited`; this makes `ClassInherited` abstract so is not instatiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering a [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).
The solution is to use [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/988930276bc3147f)), to ensure that only one copy of base class members are inherited by grand-childs:

```
// Interfaces
class InterfaceBase
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

class InterfaceInherited : virtual public InterfaceBase
{
};

// Classes
class ClassBase : virtual public  InterfaceBase
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
};

class ClassInherited : public ClassBase, public InterfaceInherited
{
};

int main()
{
    ClassBase myBase; // OK
    ClassInherited myInherited; // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you cleaned it up a little bit too. Increase indentation and remove some lines. There's no reason that this should require scrolling. See my edit of OP:s post.

Comment: Some compilers will [warn](https://godbolt.org/z/znEdEv) you about this inheritance structure. These warnings can be [ignored or silenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864550/c-inheritance-via-dominance-warning).